# Applying the knife cut tool

Tags: knife-tool

is there a way to apply the cut used by the knife tool with another button rather than hitting the Enter key? can I change that? thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 3):

You can change keys assigned to certain functions in keymap, knife:
[image]

Just go to Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Search for **knife** and find Confirm command

Comment: Thank you Miko much appreciation <3